# How can I destroy Possibility Storm?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If an opponent plays [Possibility Storm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=369013) , what would be the best way to destroy it? If I played a card which allowed me to destroy target enchantment, would this destroy Possibility Storm before my card becomes exiled or would I need to rely on one of the cards I need to draw?

Also does Possibility Storm trigger when playing creatures or lands/basic lands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It triggers whenever you cast a spell from your hand, no matter what kind of spell. This includes an instant or sorcery you might play to try to destroy it, as well as creatures. (Playing lands is not casting a spell - it's a special action you can do.)

So yes, it's difficult to destroy. Keeping it from ever reaching the battlefield by countering it is of course the easiest way. If you happen to have something on the battlefield with an ability that can destroy it, like a [Keening Apparition](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Keening%20Apparition) that'll work too. Similarly, if you're lucky enough to have a spell with Flashback already in your graveyard like [Ray of Revelation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ray%20of%20Revelation), you could use that - it's not cast from your hand, so it's not affected.

But otherwise, yes, you'll have to rely on luck - cast your spells, and hope you hit something good. Do note that you don't necessarily *have* to destroy it; you could well cast a vanilla 1/1 creature and luck into something enormous, and your opponent is just as dead if you kill them without being able to control what you cast!

Comment: There are some lands that can help you pitch Ray of Revelation to the graveyard. Spells with cast triggers (e.g., Ulamog) will also work, though the Possibility Storm trigger will still resolve in that case.

Comment: re: cast triggers;
Conspire on Gleeful Sabotage will work. (since the copy is not cast from hand)

Answer (score 3):

This question can be answered just like a question about Standstill [that was asked earlier this week](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12287/is-there-a-way-to-beat-standstill), by User Akedren.

Basically one great way to get rid of enchantments, which are permanents, is to pull them off the table or otherwise destroy them without casting a spell from your hand.

To quote the answer I mentioned above:

> You can cycle Resounding Wave targeting [Possibility Storm] and a
>   land, as cycling is an activated ability it won't cause [Possibility
>   Storm] to trigger.
>
> > 702.27a Cycling is an activated ability that functions only while the card with cycling is in a player’s hand. “Cycling [cost]” means
> >     “[Cost], Discard this card: Draw a card.”
>
> .- Akedren

Also if the board is not empty you can easily use [creatures that have abilites that allow you to destroy enchantments](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[destroy]+[target]+[enchantment]&tough=+%3E=[1]).

Answer (score 0):

Casting [Ulamog, the Infinite Gyre](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ulamog%2C%20the%20Infinite%20Gyre) will destroy possibility storm, as the "when you cast" ability on Ulamog still triggers, even though Ulamog gets replaced with a different creature.

Possibility Storm only affects cards cast from your hand, so if you have ways of casting removal spells from other zones, that will work.  If you have [Ray of Revelation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ray%20of%20Revelation) in your hand, you could wait until you have 8 cards in hand and then discard it, thus enabling you to play it via flashback.  Alternatively, [Nivix, Aerie of the Firemind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nivix%2C%20Aerie%20of%20the%20Firemind) can let you play removal spells from exile.

Baring those specific cards in your deck, play a card with the same type as your removal (for example, if you have [Disenchant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Disenchant) in your deck, play other instants) and eventually Possibility Storm will have your spell turn into the removal spell you need.

Answer (score -3):

I built A Nikol Bolas deck and recently added this card and had the same question. this was the answer. The player casting the spell has the choice as to whether or not the card ability happens first as cased below..

603.3b If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, each player, in APNAP order, puts triggered abilities he or she controls on the stack in any order he or she chooses.

And again below.

101.4. If multiple players would make choices and/or take actions at the same time, the active player (the player whose turn it is) makes any choices required, then the next player in turn order (usually the player seated to the active player’s left) makes any choices required, followed by the remaining nonactive players in turn order. Then the actions happen simultaneously. This rule is often referred to as the “Active Player, Nonactive Player (APNAP) order” rule.

Hope this helped you with your playing :) Good Luck and Have fun!

Comment: What is the other trigger here?

Comment: sorry let me fix what I said. If you are the one that controls possibility storm you get to choose if you get the effect of the card that you cast. If you do not control it then really you are somewhat screwed. there are ways to get rid of it and one way that I found works relatively well is to have Liliana Vess on the field so that you can use her -3 effect put a destroy enchantment card on top of your deck activate a card of the same type on top of your deck and then cast that spell. Also the second spell goes into your grave not into exile if anybody needs to know that.

Comment: I don't think you fully understand how Possibility Storm interacts with spells. The sequence of events is:
(1) player casts spell;
(2) storm triggers;
(3) storm resolves, exiling spell, cast second spell from library;

The original spell's effect never happens because it is removed from the stack before it has a chance to resolve.

The rule you quote is for the case when multiple triggered abilities would be put on the stack at the same time.